# Splunk inputlookup and result extraction

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to do a domain search and check to see if a domain in the CSV was visited but I'm getting nothing.

What I'm using:

```
index="suricata" sourcetype="suricata:dns" dns.answers{}.rrname="*"
[ | inputlookup domains.csv 
| rename bad_domain as dest_ip | fields dest_ip ]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the suricata:dns sourcetype has a field called "dest_ip".  If it does not then you'll need a `rename` command in the subsearch.

Second, try adding `| format` to the end of the subsearch.  Run the subsearch by itself to see what it produces.  That result string then becomes part of the main search.